# Check who is logged in Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

how to check whether the user is logged in or not from admin panel

what are the changes i need to make in models.py and admin.py to achieve this

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: I think, for this you need to change in admin package, which  are installed with django.

Comment: how to change ?

Comment: You want to see all the users that are currently logged in through the Django Admin, or you want to see who opened Django Admin?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really. Django Contrib Admin doesn't track this information. The most you can get is if User has `is_staff` or `is_superuser` to check if they could potentially visit `django.contrib.admin` interface.

Answer (score 1):

im assuming you have two functions in your views.py

1. loginUser
2. logoutUser

create a model with user as foreignkey, for storing logged users
eg. class loggedUsersModel

now in loginUser function

```
loggedUsersModel(user = request.user).save()
```

and in logoutUser function

```
loggedUsersModel(user = request.user).delete()
```

this will save loggedUsers

and register loggedUsersModel in admin.py using

```
admin.site.register(loggedUsersModel)
```